# Property does not exist on generic type T

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I do not understand the error I am getting below

Here is a minimal reproducible example

```js
type Left = {
    element: 0
}

type Right = {
    element: 1
}

interface Typings {
    "left": Left
    "right": Right
}

function foo<T extends keyof Typings>(obj: T) {
    console.log(obj.element)
                 // ^^^^^^^
                 // Property 'element' does not exist on type 'T'.
}
```

Of course I can still copy-paste my function

```js
function fooLeft(obj: Left) {
    console.log(obj.element)
}

function fooRight(obj: Right) {
    console.log(obj.element)
}
```

It works perfectly, but it doesn't seem clean... How can I avoid copy-pasting my function?

I cannot use an union, in the actual code several parameters depend on `Typings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
keyof Typings
```

This means the strings `"left" | "right"` which are the *keys of* `Typings`. You seem to want the types of the properties instead `Left | Right`.

To do that, you want `T` to be the union type of all of its properties. You do that by indexing the type by all of it's own keys.

```
function foo<T extends Typings[keyof Typings]>(obj: T) {
    console.log(obj.element) // obj is: Left | Right
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=14&pln=11&pc=19#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhBmwoF4oG8BQVtQgGwgFsIA7YALigAYMBfDDUSKAJQEsBzACyVUx1wFiZSgEY6DNmQgAneAEMAxtAAq4KRwDO6LDgBEBRHspxEu7Hpmcex1teASM8AK4lFwNgHsSUeJ88APCq4AB7ApAAm2mpgGpoA2gDWECCe8FAxcQC6AHwAFJ4ARgBWlCoAlDoCit6angQAdHieHAUlDfhEpMDldEA)